# finding first and last occurrence of a string using awk or sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I couldn't find what I am looking for online so I hope someone can help me here. I have a file with the following lines:

> CON/Type/abc.sql
>   CON/Type/bcd.sql
>   CON/Table/last.sql
>   CON/Table/first.sql
>   CON/Function/abc.sql
>   CON/Package/foo.sql

What I want to do is to find the first occurrence of Table, print a new string and then find last occurrence and print another string. For example, output should look like this:

> CON/Type/abc.sql
>   CON/Type/bcd.sql
>   set define on
>   CON/Table/last.sql
>   CON/Table/first.sql
>   set define off
>   CON/Function/abc.sql
>   CON/Package/foo.sql

As you can see, after finding first occurrence of Table I printed "set define on" before the first occurrence. For the last occurrence I printed "set define off" after last match of Table. Can someone help me write an awk script? Using sed would be okay too.

Note: The lines with Table can appear in the first line of the file or middle or last. In this case they appear in the middle of the rest of the lines.

Comment: Are the lines containing Table always contiguous or could there be a line that doesn't contain Table in between the first and the last?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F/ '$2=="Table"{if (!f)print "set define on";f=1} f && $2!="Table"{print "set define off";f=0} 1' file
CON/Type/abc.sql
CON/Type/bcd.sql
set define on
CON/Table/last.sql
CON/Table/first.sql
set define off
CON/Function/abc.sql
CON/Package/foo.sql
```

#### How it works

- `-F/`

  Set the field separator to `/`
- `$2=="Table"{if (!f)print "set define on";f=1}`

  If the second field is `Table`, then do the following: (a) if flag `f` is zero, then print `set define on`; (b) set flag `f` to one (true).
- `f && $2!="Table"{print "set define off";f=0}`

  If flag `f` is true and the second field is not `Table`, then do the following: (a) print `set define off`; (b) set flag `f` to zero (false).
- `1`

  Print the current line.

#### Alternate Version

As suggested by Etan Reisner, the following does the same thing with the logic slightly reorganized, eliminating the need for the `if` statement:

```
awk -F/ '$2=="Table" && !f {print "set define on";f=1} $2!="Table" && f {print "set define off";f=0} 1' file
```

Comment: You could move the `f` test outside the first block with `!f &&` and save the `if` but otherwise exactly my thoughts.

Comment: thank you to everyone who participated on this. this is what i was looking for. thanks again